# Posting custom object to MVC controller with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an array of custom objects aswell as a few unrelated strings, that I would like to post to an MVC controller, however I do not seem to be able to get them properly in the controller.

Here is my ajax request:

```
var objects = new Array();

objects.push({
item1: "1",
item2: "2",
item3: "3"
});

$.ajax({
     url: '/Account/Post',
     data: {
         objects: JSON.stringify({objects: objects}),
         username: $("#username").val()
     },
     type: 'POST',
     success: function () {
     },
     error: function () {
     }
});
```

And here is my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(Objects[] objects, string username)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Here is my Objects class:

```
    public class Objects
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }

    public string Item2 { get; set; }

    public string Item3 { get; set; }

    public string Item4 { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have errors? Is the controller getting called? Have you looked at HTTP requests via whatever javascript debugger?

Comment: The controller is called, but the object array is null

Comment: What does the Objects class look like?

Comment: Edited my post :)

Comment: The capitalization of ItemX is different. C# is case sensitive for objects.

Comment: Changing it doesnt make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Removing the JSON.stringify fixed my problem for some unknown reason!

Comment: I didn't notice at first but The line in your ajax call "objects: JSON.stringify({objects: objects})" should actually be : "objects: JSON.stringify(objects)"

Comment: the reason is because the server wants an actual object, not a string. $.ajax will serialise it under the hood for transmission. If you pass it a string (via stringify) it'll be serialised as one single string variable. If you pass it an object, it'll serialise it properly. Watch the request varibles in the network tab of your browser's dev tools and you'll see the difference in what's contained in the request body.